# Angular2 - ngModel - Concatenating model with loop value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've a an `[(ngModel)]` binding in my template which goes like,

```
<tbody *ngFor="let item of projParameters; let i = index">
....
....
<textarea placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="'projectViewService.projData.explanation'+item.value" [editable]="isFormEditable"></textarea>
</tbody>
```

While we execute the code, It is not getting binded with the textarea as it has been showing as a text like, (where it should show the value).

```
projectViewService.projData.explanation+item.value
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Why you are concatenating??

Comment: @Sanoj_V Because the **explanation** will be a static string across three `<td>` where as the `item.value` alone will be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround to achieve what you want is

```
[(ngModel)]="this['projectViewService.projData.explanation'+ item.value]"
```

---

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjwzwr)

Comment: Thanks for this workaround!. I saw your working example too. In my case my textarea is getting populated as empty.. :(

Comment: OK well, at least we are getting somewhere :) are you sure that `projectViewService.projData.explanation${item.value}` is properly defined? Maybe try with a simpler example to make sure it all works fine, and work your way up from there

Comment: Sure.. Trying! Thanks again

Comment: This has worked! => `projectViewService.projData['explanation'+item.value]` Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Remove the single quotes and try

```
[(ngModel)]="projectViewService.projData.explanation+item.value"
```